# How to check for consecutive double character in a Java String

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to identify a String if it has consecutive characters that are the same. So, I want a method that will return the following:

- "blah" - returns false
- "blaah" - returns true
- "blab" - returns false

So far, I have come up with this:

```
public static boolean hasConsecutiveDuplicateCharacter(String str) {
    return (str.matches("(.)\\1"));
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Use `pattern` and `matcher`. `matches` checks for the whole string.

Comment: There are already two similar answers so I won't post mine, but [here](https://ideone.com/MB1cuv)'s an ideone testing one of such solutions.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for raising a duplicate. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex logic involving a backreference is logically correct.  However, `String#matches()` will match the entire string against the pattern.  Hence, if you use a pattern covering the full string your helper method should work:

```
.*(.)\\1.*
```

**Code:**

```
public static boolean hasConsecutiveDuplicateCharacter(String str) {
    return (str.matches(".*(.)\\1.*"));
}
```

Whether you decide to use `matches()` or to use a formal pattern matcher depends on your needs etc., but in any case I believe `matches` will use a matcher under the hood anyway.

Comment: For others who may visit this page...this is the solution that I tried and its working fine for me now. The other posts are good to read too. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the pattern to match the whole string. Instead, you want to find a matching substring.

To do so, use [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

```
public static boolean hasConsecutiveDuplicateCharacter(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - very useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ss = { "AABB", "abc", "azzo", "suio", "suii" };

    String regex = "([a-zA-Z])\\1";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    for (String string : ss) {
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

[image]